# Is It possible to use web method in C# class?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using web method in C# class file(i.e not a partial class of any web form) and I have html file. I just want to call web method from html file using JQuery AJAX GET and POST methods. Is it possible to do this? Is this have any sense? or i must want use asp web form?

Comment: If you can't use something more appropriate like Web API, I suggest  you implement `IHttpHandler`s. Web Forms also implement IHttpHandler but if you just want to handle ajax requests you shouldn't use a web form. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question it's important that you first understand the prurpose of having a web service.Web services allow us to expose any piece of software **over the internet** and allow clients to consume it.

In .NET ASMX web services we expose software to the outside world by decorating methods with the `[WebMethod]` attribute.But even if we apply the `[WebMethod]` attribute our method will not be available over the internet unless it's inisde a:

1. .asmx web service file
2. .aspx web page

Hopefully now you understand why you can't simply define a `[WebMethod]` inside a standard C# class.Below is a simple example of calling an ASMX web service from a plain html page:

**MyService.asmx:**

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string GreetUser(string name)
    {
        return String.Format("Hello {0}",name);
    }
}
```

**Index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnCallService").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyService.asmx/GreetUser",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{name:"' + $("#txtName").val() + '"}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (errordata) {
                        console.log(errordata);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" value="Call Service" id="btnCallService" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Denis, For makes me understand the web method usage.

Comment: Sure. I will. Implementation in progress

Comment: I'm getting exception 500(" internal server error").

Comment: Did you add a web service to your web application called MyService.asmx?Do you have a [WebMethod] called GreetUser?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Your html file can include a  tag with functions that make ajax calls. 
Here is a simple example from W3School's site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

You see that the button has an 'onClick' event, which calls the loadDoc function.
And this is the function:

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the link to the tutorial's page:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax Call on HTML will look very similar to this

```
 var options = {
                type: "POST",
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/FileLocationWhereWebMethodIsDefined") %>',
                data: "{'Add Parameters if your web method needs it'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    //jQuery(".overlay").show();
                    //jQuery(".progress").show();
                },
               success: function (msg) {
               },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               //     jQuery(".overlay").hide();
                 //   jQuery(".progress").hide();
                    throw Error; // "error";
                }
            };
            jQuery.ajax(options);
```